# A>=B>=C operators in C?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (2 >= 1 >= 1)
        printf("1\n");
    if (200 >= 100 >= 100)
        printf("2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

nyc@nyc:~/PRG$ gcc sample.c

> nyc@nyc:~/PRG$ ./a.out  1

Why does this program print only 1 even if the second expression evaluates to TRUE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C doesn't support chaining operators like that. You'll have to divide that expression into two, seperated by the logical AND operator:

```
if(2 >= 1 && 1 >= 1)
if(200 >= 100 && 100 >= 100)
```

otherwise, it is executed as

```
if((2 >= 1) >= 1)
if((200 >= 100) >= 100)
```

and the left part will execute first and will evaluate to 1 if that condition is true and will evaluate to 0, if it is false and so, the above conditions becomes

```
if(1 >= 1) /* which is true */
if(1 >= 100) /* which is false */
```

Answer (score 5):

The second expression does **not** evaluate to true.

The C standard defines the comparison operators ('>', '>=', '==', etc.) to return an `int` result, either 0 (for false) or 1 (for true). Furthermore `>=` is evaluated from left to right. (Formally this is called the *associativity* of the operator).

So `2>=1>=1` is equivalent to `(2>=1)>=1`. This is `1 >= 1`, which evaluates as 1.

`200>=100>=100` is computed as `(200>=100)>=100` which is `1 >= 100` which evaluates to 0.

Comment: basically its 1>=1 and 1>=100 right?

Comment: Probably shouldn't use the term order of evaluation here, as that typically refers to order of evaluation of sub-expressions, something which is completely unrelated to operator precedence.

Comment: Indeed. Formally I should use *associativity*. Scrapped the comment, and amended the answer.

Answer (score 4):

First note that `2>=1>=1` is probably a nonsense expression, it is not equivalent to a mathematical interval. The code literally means:

- `2>=1`. If 2 is larger than or equal to 1, evaluate to value 1 (true), otherwise evaluate to value 0 (false).
- `2>=1>=1`. If the evaluated value from sub-expression `2>=1` is larger than or equal to 1, evaluate to 1 (true), otherwise evaluate to 0 (false).

To check if a value is inside a given internal, you would have to write `if(2>=x && x>=1)`.

---

That being said, there are three different things to consider for the actual evaluation: *operator precedence*, *operator associativity* and *order of evaluation of operands*.

Operator precedence merely determines the priority of different operators in relation to each other. Since the only operator in the expression is `>=`, they all have the same precedence, since they all belong to the same group of operators: the relational operators.

Operator associativity is something that applies when operators of same precedence are found in the same expression. The operator associativity for the relational operators is left-to-right, meaning that if two relational operators are found in the same expression, their operands will get grouped from left to right, making this particular expression equivalent to `(2>=1) >= 1`.

The term *order of evaluation* is rather loosely used in C, but usually refers to the order of evaluation of operands/sub-expressions, which is something completely unrelated to operator precedence. Consider `a() >= b() >= c()`. While operator precedence and associativity guarantees that this expression is equivalent to `(a() >= b()) >= c()`, it guarantees nothing about in which order the operators are evaluated. In this case, the operator precedence/associativity has *nothing* to do with the order in which the functions are executed, but only in which order their results are used.

In most cases, the order of evaluation of operands is unspecified in C, meaning that we can't know it nor rely on it. (Some special operators like `&& || ?:` and `,` have guaranteed order of evaluation of operands, most operators do not.) Therefore if the order of evaluation would matter for the result, we best split up the expression in several lines instead.

In the specific case of `2>=1>=1`, there's only integer constant literals, so order of evaluation doesn't matter here. But please don't mix up operator precedence with order of evaluation, they are different things.