# Associativity interpretation?

Tags: c

In C we often say that the operators are left-associative and right associative,
A left-associative operator is for example which starts from the left side and ends on the right of the user.

If for example in case of assignment operator `x=y;` for `x=5` and `y=20`, is like saying put value of `y` in the `x`, that seems very legitimate.

but in cases like `if(x>y)`, '>` operator has left associativity.
Means it computes **Is x greater than y? FALSE**.

But, why we go like this we can also say it reading from right associativity
**Is y smaller than x? FALSE**

Why use left associativity when the output comes same in both cases?

For a ternary operation as Mat says.

The answer to `x>y>z` really depends on the direction, the answer will vary from right to left , to left to right. but that is because of different comparisons done at different stage.

Both the answers will evaluate a value, but why do we say that we will chose only the one with left associativity

Comment: Do not confuse associativity with commutativity.

Comment: Read wikipage on [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219809/a-b-c-operators-in-c/32220905#32220905) explains the differences between operator precedence, operator associativity and order of evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associativity concept come in play only when the expression has more than one operator. It is a property of the operator in the expression, not the operands. It define how brackets are inserted, not what the operator means.

```
operator       : Some R
expression     : x R y R z
left to right  : (x R y) R z
right to left  : x R (y R z)
```

**edit:**
[Reference of operator associativity in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: both values return some value what makes us decide the left or right?

Comment: I really wonder what was the basis standardization of this associativity

Answer (score 2):

You are confused about operator **precedence** and operator **associativity**.

Operator associativity only applies with operators with the same precedence. For example:

```
1 - 2 + 3
```

`+` and `-` have the same precedence, and they are left-associative, which means the above is equivalent to:

```
(1 - 2) + 3
```

Comment: I think it is more about associativity why do we prefer one direction while the statement can still be calculated to a valid answer the other way.

Comment: @MaMba, the statement cannot be calcuated "the other way" as that would mean `1 - (2 + 3)`, which is -4, not +2.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused between the **Associativity** and **Readability**.

> Why use left associativity when the output comes same in both cases?

This is true for the readability but not for all the evaluations of expressions.

Consider:

```
x=10, y=20, z=10
```

Now, **left to right associativity**:

```
x<y<z => (x<y)<z => (10<20)<10 => (1<10) =>TRUE
```

Now, **right to reft associativity**:

```
x<y<z => x<(y<z) => 10<(20<10) => (10<0) =>FALSE
```

Now, the concept of associativity arrives only when there are multiple existence of same operator.