# Simple 'else if' statement is not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    printf("Hello world! Please enter your age\n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age <= 50) {
        printf("You are still young to change the world\n");
    }
    else if (70 >= age >50) {
        printf("You are now old, but don't worry\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You are extremely old\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I entered age 51 and it gives "you are extremely old". The `else if` statement is not working.

Comment: C doesn't support operator chaining like that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32219872/3049655) for more details.

Comment: The `else` belongs to the condition `(age <= 50)` and enforces already that `(age > 50)` (or `!(age <= 50)`) when your condition is evaluated. You don't need a compound condition in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if ( 70>=age>50 ){
```

In C this is not how you do this. Instead try this -

```
else if (age>50 && age <=70){    // age in between 50 and 70(including)
```

Comment: thnxs, its working :))

Comment: `age <= 50` has already been tested, so in fact `if ( age <= 70 )` would be the best solution